# VScode is forcing my extensions to be installed on WSL

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to install platformIO an IOT tools extension and VScode installs it on wsl with no option for me to change to a local installation. Because it has a lot of dependence on IO and the extension just uses python it is really important for that it is installed locally. Is there any way to do this?

[image: before install]
[image: after install]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The green space in the bottom left tells you what "OS" VScode is using (win or one of the multiple WSL you might have on your system). It looks like this for WSl
[image]

or empty like this for windows

[image]

just click on it to change it. Extentions are installed to the respective environment/OS.